# I want my Angular to check two links (base path) instead of just one for path assurance in ionic angular

Tags: angular, typescript, api, ionic-framework

Recently we had an issue of transferring domain name which had let to huge downtime in our product, which we want to avoid at all cost. So, for future reference, I thought of doing something where it will first check through the domain name, if not then through the static ip itself.

This may not be of importance since i know the top most best solution would be to just simply use the static ip and eliminate the domain name itself, but now we are looking forward (future work) to build a copy server, a mirror but with seperate IP so that if one server goes down, it switches to another server.

Here is the following code I have which I've tried on my end to do but failed to do:

````
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  // API path
  basePath = 'first ip address';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient) {}

  // Handle API errors
  handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      (data):Observable<any> => {
        return this.http.post<any>('second ip address', data).pipe(retry(0));
      };
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(
        'Backend returned code: ' + error.status + '; body was: ' + error.message);
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError(
      'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  }

  // Create a new item
  postData(data): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .post<any>(this.basePath, data)
      .pipe(
        retry(0), // 2
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
} ```

If anyone can guide me that would be helpful, thanks
````